# how do i edit compressed gz xml file, compress and save it back, with php?

Tags: php, xml, compression, gzip, cdata

I want to add, replace some tags, CDATAS etc.want to edit and save the file back replacing the previous one.same compression level and type (it's a gzip archive) used in the file, to be maintained. I know how to read complete xml file. Here is how much I know. need to write and compress it back. The original compressed file name is "mycompressedgzipfile.gzip".

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://mycompressedgzipfile.xml",'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: same way you opened it. establish a stream with zlib settings, and write to it.

Comment: can i use gzwrite() ? is that the one

Comment: You just save it as you opened it (sidenote: you can spare the two last parameters as you open it most probably). Just store the whole filename incl. the wrapper in front into a variable and use that variable. You can use that variable then with [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.asXML)